# How to assign values to javascript object through angularjs ng-click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, javascript-objects, angularjs-ng-click

In the below code I am trying to set some values for google map's lat long, when I call the change function which is bound to ng-click directive, the page doesn't load, but without change() func everything loads pretty well. I might be missing some core concepts of angular that is because I have started working on it just 10 days before, kindly correct me here and if someone can suggest me another way to change my lat long with button click, I will be really thankful for that suggestion.

```
app.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope){

   // $scope.change=function(){
    $scope.Latitude="23.200000";
    $scope.Longitude="79.225487";
    $scope.assignLat=function () {
    var lati= $scope.Latitude;
    return lati;
}
    $scope.assignLong=function () {
    var longi= $scope.Longitude;
    return longi;
       }
       console.log($scope.assignLat());
       console.log($scope.assignLong());
   // }
    var cities = [{
            city : 'India',
            desc : 'This is the best country in the world!',
            lat : $scope.assignLat(),
            long : $scope.assignLong()
        }];
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(25,80),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }
    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    $scope.markers = [];
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var createMarker = function (info){

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
            title: info.city
        });
        marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div>';

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        });

        $scope.markers.push(marker);

    }
    for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
        createMarker(cities[i]);
    }

    $scope.openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker){
        e.preventDefault();
        google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
    }
});
```

Comment: Your `change()`is supposed to end after the line console.log($scope.assignLong());`` ?

Comment: **Fix the indentation.** The lack of proper indentation makes it difficult to see what is happening. It looks like the problem is caused by nesting function assignments for `$scope.assignLat` and `$scope.assignLong` inside the `change` function.